# PlotRange problem

Tags: plotting

When I plot a list (20 points) using `ListPlot`, the plot always begins at 1 and not 30 as my `PlotRange` indicates.

```
ListPlot[data5, AxesOrigin -> {30, 0},PlotRange -> {{30, 50}, {-2 Pi, 2 Pi}}]
```

Comment: Look up `DataRange`.

Comment: Note the difference in the spacing (along the x axis) in my two different possible answers. Your question isn't unambiguous in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[{-6, 6}, 20], AxesOrigin -> {30, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> {-2 Pi, 2 Pi}, DataRange -> {30, 50}]
```

[image]

Or

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[30, 49], RandomReal[{-6, 6}, 20]}], 
 AxesOrigin -> {30, 0}, PlotRange -> {{30, 50}, {-2 Pi, 2 Pi}}]
```

[image]